# Rsa accumulator storage size

Tags: rsa, certificates, accumulators

Rsa accumulator's storage complexity is known as O(1). However, how can i calculate size of accumulator value in byte?

Answer (score 2):

If by "accumulator value" you mean $g^{\prod e_i} \bmod N$, where the $e_i$'s are the accumulated elements, then the size of this accumulator value is the same as one group element in $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ (assuming you are using RSA groups for your implementation, which most people do).

Specifically, a reasonable $N$ would be a 2048-bit number, which means your accumulator value would be $2048/8 = 256$ bytes.